# Weird happenings on my HTML/CSS website, possibly inheritance problems?

Tags: html, css

I have created a website in Dreamweaver in HTML and CSS. This is the url: http://bit.ly/10W69ix

So there are a couple of errors going on;

1) Try to click on the excavator logo and the website title in the header. A weird border and shape around it will appear.

2) The menu items next to the black home icon isn't appearing anymore after I clicked one of the menu items. It might also be it doesn't appear anymore in the first place. The hover and click state work fine though.

3) The footer links only have the orange padding around them when clicked, not when hovered which I do want to appear. How the heck did I made that happen.

So as you can see I'm not a pro in CSS, I think the problems occur due to an inheritance problem or something, I tried ordering my CSS in a different way but it didn't do anything.

Any help is really appreciated. I also asked a friend of mine who is good in HTML/CSS and even he couldn't figure it out, so I'm really lost.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Kind regards, Rudolf

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1):

I see issues similar to the example below with several different CSS definitions in `main.css`.
They could be causing one or more of your problems.

**Example:**

This sets an `:active` definition for *all links* (main.css, line 169):

```
.FooterText a:hover, a:active {...}
```

That has potential to overwrite other link definitions (like in your header).
I think you only want to set it for `.FooterText` links:

```
.FooterText a:hover, .FooterText a:active { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't really understand what I need to do though, how should it look like then?

Comment: I suggest searching for all combined rules in your CSS file and making sure that you are specifying the full selector (or at least a more specific selector) for each definition. I included a before and after example in my answer. Do you understand the problem I described or need more clarity?

Comment: Ah, the question got closed. Anyway, [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2SCh/) to help demonstrate. Check out the CSS portion and look for lines I have commented out and replaced (e.g. line 45)

Comment: I get it now. I applied that specific selector to all combined rules. The weird borders around my header logo and link are gone now. However, now my hover state of the header link state doesn't work anymore as it stays white.

And the lighter orange padding hover/active state of footer links are also gone; [link](http://bit.ly/10W69ix)

Comment: I still see problematic definitions in main.css. Lines 25, 29, 45, 54, 72, 89, 93, 102, 124, 133, 161, 169. Are you sure you have uploaded your updated CSS file?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to upload the css file itself. How does it look now?

Comment: Seems to work much better. How does it look to you?

Answer (score 0):

A recurring problem with your CSS seem to be the way you combine css rules.

To separate selector with `,` you need to type the full selector for each item

so `#Header a:link, a:visited` should be `#Header a:link, #Header a:visited` and so forth for all your rules..

Comment: Hi, I see you suggested something similar, the way I fixed problem 2) is with what you suggested:

.MenuBarTop a:hover, .MenuBarTop a:active {...}

Though the weird border around the header links stay regardless of adding that extra selector:

.Header a:link, .Header a:visited {...}

Comment: @Rudolf As mentioned, the same problem appears several times with different definitions in your CSS file. Follow the same pattern to fix ALL other definitions. For example, your footer link definitions might be messing with your header link definitions.